# Did apk file stores something hidden?

Tags: android

Did apk contains any hidden content that allows google play to track our computer?

I am banned in Google Play for couple years for something not my fault, so I am for years creating new Google Play accounts:
-new ip(tunneling connection, vps, etc.)
-new data (credit card, user data, etc.)
-sometimes new system, system account, etc.

Always I have after month-couple months, ban for previous violations. For what is the reason? They hides something in apk or screen? I don't know what can they track.

I am using canvas blocker, firegloves, ghostery with Google Play. Maybe they are somehow track physical adress of the device (MAC, processor id, graphics card it) or adding something hidden to APK.

Any ideas to bypass this cruel ban mechanism?

This is little non-programming question but I hope to get some knowledge from experienced devs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they track you by your certificate ? :)